# Qemu - Cannot connect to Guest ESXi

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vmware, qemu, esxi

I'm running Qemu on Windows and I can't connect to the ESXi guest and can't ping the host network gateway from the ESXi guest. I disabled all other network interface on Host machine except the internet connecting Ethernet interface. I've spent like 2 days and still can't get it working.

Any idea how to resolve the issue?

I'm using the following command to start the guest.

`qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -hda esxi.img -m 4096 -cpu Westmere -machine q35 -smp cpus=2,cores=2 -accel tcg -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::2022-:22,hostfwd=tcp::8080-:80 -device e1000,netdev=net0`

[image]

```
192.168.1.1 is the router gateway.
192.168.1.4 is the host machine IP address.
```

Esxi guest can't ping either.

Answer (score 0):

ESXi dropped support for e1000 network cards. Change from e1000 to e1000e.

Ref: https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=software&testConfig=16&productid=44381&supRel=429,&deviceCategory=software&details=1&partner=465&releases=429&operatingSystems=206&productNames=15&page=1&display_interval=10&sortColumn=Partner&sortOrder=Asc&testConfig=16

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a litle more?